# How to prevent a snap package from accessing my home directory?

Tags: security, snap

I want to use `mathpix-snipping-tool` snap package, but it has an extremely lousy [privacy policy](https://mathpix.com/privacy), in which the company says that they can collect whatever info they want, and the package has a [home interface](https://snapcraft.io/docs/home-interface) connection, which can be seen in the output of `snap connections mathpix-snipping-tool`:

```
Interface        Plug                                   Slot           Notes
...
home             mathpix-snipping-tool:home             :home          -
```

This is suspicious, because all the package does is take screenshots, upload them to an internet server, and show me LaTeX code of the formula in the screenshot, it doesn't need access to my files to do that.

How can I prevent this package from accessing my home directory (and maybe all other resources except for internet access and access to my x11 server)?

Comment: I strongly recommend NOT using software with such a lousy privacy policy.   Find an alternative, even if it doesn't have all the features of this spyware product.  Or just learn enough latex to be able to write the equations yourself.  BOYCOTT SPYWARE.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this command will do it:

```
sudo snap disconnect mathpix-snipping-tool:home :home
```

Check out https://snapcraft.io/docs/interface-management for more options.

Comment: If the package is updated, can it reconnect itself without me knowing?

Comment: In general, package managers do not reset app configs to their defaults on a simple upgrade. If you're worried about it, disable snapd's automatic updates and handle them yourself; that way you'll know right away if this is going to be a problem.